# Acts_as_taggable edit action not working correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, acts-as-taggable-on

I have acts_as_taggable setup and working but i have one problem.

For example if i create a post then add tags to it such as tech, electronics, music.

Everything works correctly.

Now when i go to edit the post the tags in the text field show up as tech electronics music.

Notice there is no commas seperating the tags so the problem is that you have to re add the commas everytime you edit the post. Otherwise if you save it then tech electronics music shows up as one tag not 3 seperate tags.

So how would i get those commas to show up in edit form.

## **My Code**

**Controller**

```
def index
    @tags = Link.tag_counts_on(:tags)

    if params[:tag].present? 
       @links = Link.tagged_with(params[:tag])
    else
       @links = Link.all
    end
end


def new
    @link = Link.new
end


def create
    @link = Link.new(link_params)

    if @link.save
      redirect_to action: "index"
      flash[:success] = "Link Added"
    else
      render 'new'
    end
end


def edit
    @link = Link.find(params[:id])
end


def update
    @link = Link.find(params[:id])

    if @link.update_attributes(link_params)
      redirect_to action: "index"
      flash[:success] = "Link Updated"
    else
      render 'edit'
    end 
end


private
    def link_params
      params.require(:link).permit(:title, :description, :url, :tag_list)
    end
```

**Edit.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@link) do |f| %>
    <div>
        <%= f.label :title, "Link Title" %>
        <%= f.text_field :title %>
    </div>

    <div>
        <%= f.label :description %>
        <%= f.text_area :description %>
    </div>

    <div>
       <%= f.label :url, "URL" %>
       <%= f.text_field :url %>
    </div>

   <div>
       <%= f.label :tags, "Tags (separated by commas)" %>
       <%= f.text_field :tag_list %>
   </div>

    <div>
        <%= f.submit "Save Changes" %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the Problem. I had to change in my form.

```
<%= f.text_field :tag_list %>
```

to

```
<%= f.text_field :tag_list, value: @post.tag_list.to_s %>
```